# Firestore onSnapshot - how to tell which individual fields changed?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I’m modeling data and have a question about the `onSnapshot` (web) listener. As pointed out in a couple posts on SO and in the docs, after the initial invocation, the listener only fetches the changed data. I am interested to know what the changed data is. If listening on a document, is it just the field or the entire document that is fetched?

In a scenario where we have a listener on a Document, and the value of a field on that document changes (or a field is added, or removed), is only that field is fetched? In other words, is this similar to placing a `child_changed/added/removed` listener on a node in the RTDB?

The intent is to determine if I should keep frequently changing Documents, which clients must listen to, in RTDB or Firestore. I prefer not to resend the entire document to the client due to only a field change, if possible.

Example. We have the following document:

```
rando_id:
  field1
  field2
  field3
```

If `field2`'s value changes, will only `field2` be the transmitted data from Firestore DB to the client? The same would apply to adding a `field4` or removing `field1`. Would just those fields be sent to the client?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The unit of storage in Firestore is the document.  There are no more granular ways to transmit data.  There is no API to tell what exactly has changed in a document - you would have to determine that yourself using a prior snapshot, if available.  You also can't target document fields in security rules.  With documents in Firestore, it's either all or nothing.

Comment: Looking at Firestore bandwidth rates, it does not appear that pricing will matter with full document fetches. Document size as it relates to latency appears to be the only concern, but even that appears borderline insignificant.

Comment: You can also restructure your data such that the more frequently fields exist in documents in a different collection.

Comment: Was just having this exact discussion with another engineer :) Also considering using rtdb to facilitate the more frequent updates. EG we are keeping chat data in rtdb because of the high number of read operations

Comment: That's a common alternative as well, yes.